# SQL Multiple Joins with Counts

Tags: mysql

I need to join 3 different MySQL tables:

- The questions table (represents a questio)
- The questions votes table (represents a like to the question when Sign=1 and an unlike when Sign=0)
- The answers table (represents a table with the answers to an specific question).

The three tables have this structure:

```
Questions
--------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  UserID  |  Title  |  Body  | Date
--------------------------------------------
|  1  |  32  |  Is it raining?  |  BodyQuestion  | 01/01/2016
|  2  |  45  |  Who are we?  |  BodyQuestion  | 02/02/2016
--------------------------------------------


QuestionsVotes
--------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  QuestionID  |  Sign
--------------------------------------------
|  1   |  1           |  1
|  2   |  2           |  1
|  3   |  1           |  0
|  4   |  1           |  1
|  5   |  2           |  0

Answers
--------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  QuestionID  |  UserID | Body
--------------------------------------------
|  1  |  1  |  45 | Yes, it is.
|  2  |  2  |  10 | Tricky question...
|  3  |  1  |  67 | In Barcelona it is not
```

What I need is a SQL query that returns, given the ID of a Question, to return as much rows as number of answers the question has received each one with the Questions.ID, Questions.UserID, Questions.Title, Questions.Body, Questions.Date, the likes associated to the question, the unlikes associated with the question, Answers.ID, Answers.UserID. As you see, the only change between the rows are the Answers fields.

```
SQL Output (for Question with ID=1)
--------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  UserID  |  Title | Body | Date | Likes | Unlikes | AnswerID | AnswerUserID
--------------------------------------------
|  1  |  32  |  Is it raining? | BodyQuestion | 01/01/2016 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 45
|  1  |  32  |  Is it raining? | BodyQuestion | 01/01/2016 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 67
```

**EDIT 1:** Example given.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the exact desired output.

Comment: Can you please edit this question and clarify what you are looking for. I read your bottom paragraph three times and still don't really get what you are asking for in terms of output.

Comment: I have added a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `ID` ,  `UserID`  ,  `Title`, `Body`, `Date`, `Likes`, `Unlikes`, `AnswerID`, `AnswerUserID`
FROM QUESTIONS q
INNER JOIN ANSWERS a ON q.`ID` = a.`QuestionID`
INNER JOIN QuestionVotes v ON q.`ID` = v.`QuestionID`
```

Comment: The problem is that 'Likes' and 'Unlikes' are not a real column, but rows in the QuestionsVotes Table that represents a like when Sign=1 and an unlike when Sign=0. Thank you anyway.